# Storing JavaScript in database for later use

Tags: javascript, database, data-structures, storage

I need to store JavaScript code somewhere on server.

It will be often extracted and presented to users through web interface in two forms:

- code itself (as text)
- visual representation of that code

The question is how it would be better to store code?

Database? If so, then I have at least two options:

- storing code as a plain text
- storing pre-generated syntax tree of that code

What's actually easier (~faster): parsing code to syntax tree or generating code from syntax tree?

Maybe some other solutions? JSON?

What are the best practices?

Comment: If you wanted to preserve formatting, whitespace, etc - you'd have to store as plain text, right?

Comment: I'd store the plain text. This also allows to store stuff that does not compile, for example syntax errors, and preserves user input (indentation and stuff). I am assuming this is for some kind of online IDE.

Comment: @Mike Christensen Yes, or I can format it with something like BeautifyJS in a standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets say this is your javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('example');
</script>
```

you can save it in the following format in database so whenever you will extract it back it will get parsed easily, **with code type equals text** and **collation=utf8_general_ci**

```
&lt;script type=\&quot;text/javascript\&quot;&gt;
alert(\&#039;example\&#039;);
&lt;/script&gt;
```

tell me if you have any queries....

Comment: Why are you escaping the HTML?

Comment: could you be more specific about which part of HTML I am escaping?

Comment: You're replacing characters with their respective HTML entities. The script isn't HTML, so there's really no need to do that.

Comment: I think he's answering the question of how you *display* JavaScript in a browser without running it.

Comment: No problem will occur here when you will insert it into database, but when you will call this code back in order to make sure the output code is formatted in the javascript format without any quotes missing or so, this formatting is necessary because you know query will run in PHP and it needs escape sequence to determine **"** etc or otherwise it will mess up the output. therefore this formatting.

Comment: @Mike I am trying to answer is how to store javascript in the Mysql database and then call it back with proper formatting to use it in your code. btw http://www.q2w3.ru/code-insert-manager-wordpress-plugin/ for wordpress also follow this same technique.

Comment: @Anfual PHP? Really? :)

Comment: I am a PHP guy, I prefer PHP for sever side coding and DB purposes. Its upto you whatever you prefer my task was to tell you store javascript code in DB and in the format I explained above.